# Maximal cardinality of collection of cross-like shapes in the plane

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Here are two related problems I have encountered several times before:

> $i)$ Show that there can only be countably many pairwise disjoint **crosses** in the plane.
> $ii)$ Show that  there can only be countably many pairwise disjoint **figure eights** in the plane.

A cross is defined as the union of two line segments intersecting in their interiors. A figure eight is defined as a loop $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ with exactly one internal self-intersection. These have been answered on this site before, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2057302/620957) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767857/620957). I am interested in some generalisations to these problems:

> What is the maximal cardinality of a set of pairwise disjoint objects in the plane, if the objects are the union of:
>
> Q1: **Three line segments** sharing a common end point and non-overlapping (i.e. pairwise non-parallel).
> Q2: **Four continuous paths** with a common end point, and otherwise non-intersecting and non-self-intersecting.
> Q3: **Three continuous paths** with a common end point, and otherwise non-intersecting and non-self-intersecting.

The objects in Q1 are three-armed rigid crosses (like the Mercedes logo). In Q2 and Q3 we have four- and three-armed wobbly starfish shapes, as it were. I strongly suspect they are all countable. If we can prove it for Q3, then Q1-2 are also countable immediately. If needed, you can assume additional smoothness to the paths, to maybe employ Taylor approximations or something.

I dont' think it is necessary to assume the paths are non-intersecting, as long they do not completely overlap. The important bit is that there is some point with three or four different paths going out from it locally.

---

The usual proofs for $i)$ and $ii)$ go something like this (paraphrased from answers on this site):

$i)$: Let $C_\varepsilon$ be the subset of crosses with shortest arm length $\ge\varepsilon$. The centers of two crosses in $C_\varepsilon$ can only be so-and-so close to each other, so $C_\varepsilon$ is countable. The whole collection of crosses is a countable union $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}C_{1/n}$, so it is countable.

Note that I think this proof is somewhat lacking in how it determines the minimum distance of crosses. In particular, I think it is necessary to consider the angle of the cross as well, but it doesn't seem hard to fix. Given two crosses in $C_\varepsilon$ that additionally have their smaller angles $\ge\varphi$, I am sure one can find a lower bound for the distance between their centers with some elementary geometry. But if the angles are not controlled, then two crosses in $C_\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily close.

$ii)$: Assign two rational points to each figure eight, one in the interior of each of the two bounded regions it makes. Since two figure eights can't be assigned the same pair of rational points without intersecting, we have an injection into $\mathbb Q^2\times \mathbb Q^2$.

---

Now, the proofs of $i)$ and $ii)$ are completely different in flavour. One is simply geometric and focuses on the intersection point. The other requires the closed loops of the figure eight to do the rational point trick. However, I think that the "real" problem (in some sense) with the figure eights is not their loops but their self-intersection.

In this vein, the objects in Q2 can be seen as open-ended figure eights. I think there should be a proof using the idea of minimal distances between crosses but accounting for the non-rigid shapes of the paths in some way. I think Q1 can be proven very similarly to $i)$ by looking at some measure of size for the objects. But I am most interested in Q3 of course, since that implies the others.

Comment: Relevant is the google search [triods + countable](https://www.google.com/search?q=triods+countable). See also [How many tacks fit in the plane?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27244/15780) *AND* [Show disjoint $\theta$-sets in the plane is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2217816/13130) *AND* [Prove that any family of disjoint 8-signs on the plane is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185466/13130) *AND* [Prove by elementary methods: the plane cannot be covered by countably many copies of the letter "Y"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2014171/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: *AND* [Prove that there can be at most countably many disjoint letter T's in the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763826/13130). Also, see [this 6 January 1990 sci.math question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/KXyOW2K3l9g/aDwjOvIhl9MJ) and the Bull. AMS paper [*An elementary proof of the triod theorem*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-04/S0002-9939-1970-0263049-9/) by C. R. Pittman (1970).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Though most of those links do not answer my question, it seems like "triod" is the keyword I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't read your question very closely, because I'm in the middle of a lot of "day job contract work stuff" that requires careful focus and proofreading and I didn't feel up to having to think very hard, but I needed a break (taking another one right now), so I spent a few moments googling what I thought might be of use. This is true for many of my Stack Exchange comments, by the way.

Comment: Doesn't the Pittman paper prove what you want?

Comment: @Max It seems Theorem 1 according to which there  exists  only  a  countable  number  of mutually  exclusive  simple  triods  in  the  plane
answers the question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, Max. And Dave, I would be happy to give you the bounty, and accept, but I think there needs to be an answer posted for that.

Comment: *happy to give you the bounty ... needs to be an answer posted* --- I don't have the time now to go through the details and write a reasonably careful and informative answer (and I rarely bother answering without doing this, because I prefer to keep my answers as mostly significant things and not clutter them with lots of "quickie things"), so as far as I'm concerned, anyone who's game for writing such an answer, have at it. Incidentally, there's no reason you --- Milten --- can't answer your own question. In fact, [I've done this at least once myself](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/451/264).